# How can i add bold to this menu?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://www.les-toiles.co/
pass:dgdesign

This is demo:

http://venusdemo.com/wpopal/mix/fashion/

In this demo menu is bold ... and me not and I wanted to add I

This is the code that I found

```
    .navbar-mega .navbar-nav > li > a {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0;
  /* 3 */
  /* 3 */
  /* 4 */
  /* 6 */
  /* 6 */
  /* 7 */
  font-size: 12px;
  /* 9 */
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  /* 9 */
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is some password for your site..what is that???

Comment: the text in the 2nd site is bold due to  `font-weight: 900;`

Comment: Could not understand what you are trying to do. If there is something you wanna do about Bold text, then there is a thing `font-weight` in the code. Reduce its value to reduce boldness

Comment: It already is bold, but you're using a different font than the demo(Quicksand), that's why it looks different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this css in your css file

```
#main-menu > li > a{ font-weight: bold; }
```

the font-family important declaration is keeping the css from working, so remove this css rule from front-style.css

```
body{ font-family: "Quicksand" !important; }
```

Comment: If you still want the Quicksand font you could get rid of the 'important tag' and find the bold version of [Quicksand](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/quicksand) and apply it to `#main-menu > li >a`

Comment: To use a webfont bold version in addition to the basic version the fontsquirrel website protomancer linked to above has a really nice [fonts for the web packaging utility](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).

Comment: .body{ font-family: "Quicksand" !important; }
#main-menu > li > a{ font-weight: bold; }

Comment: I told you to remove the existing rule that causes the Quicksand" font to be used, not add another rule.

Comment: Ok but where is the old font?

Comment: It is being applied the element by the rule 'body, h3 {font-family: Quicksand"!important;}' in the file front-style.css on line 2.

Comment: in style.css ori themplate.css?

Comment: The inspector says it is in a file called front-style.css

Answer (score 0):

You font : QuickSand is ruining it. Change that to a normal font and add font-weight:bold; to your css class nav